# Box.net v2 API has a java client library

Tags: java, box-api

I was looking for some library that make easier the manage of the box v2 api in java, i found this

https://github.com/box/box-java-sdk

but am not sure if it use the v2 box.net api. some knows a library in java ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That library was built by a third-party on the **v1** API. If there is one in development for v2, we'll post about it here.

Answer (score 0):

The Temboo SDK (which comes in Java, and several other languages) currently supports the Box v2 API and is pretty constantly updated to support new Box API releases. Take a look at https://live.temboo.com/library/Library/Box/

The SDK is an open download, and can be found at https://www.temboo.com/download. However, you'll need a (free) Temboo account to do anything with it.

(Full disclosure: I work at Temboo)

Answer (score 0):

Try the V2 box.net java api library: https://github.com/box/box-java-sdk-v2